# PHP : How to trim last string inside the loop

Tags: php

Is there other way to trim this inside the loop? I have a loop and inside, i need to rtrim the last loop row, but what happen is it removes all character each of the last right string.

If I use this method, it works.

```
$plus = "";
for($i=0; $i<6; $i++){
    $plus .= 'total'.$i."+";
}
echo rtrim($plus,'+');
//output
total0+total1+total2+total3+total4+total5
```

But how if i need to rtrim it inside the loop? Because I need for some reason

```
for($i=0; $i<6; $i++){
    $plus = 'total'.$i."+";
    echo rtrim($plus,'+');
}
//output says
total0total1total2total3total4total5

//This should be like
//total0+total1+total2+total3+total4+total5
```

Comment: Put an if statement inside the loop, so you execute the trim only on the last element.

Comment: Yes, but why?  What is a good reason for doing it the second way instead of the first way?

Comment: I have bunch of codes this is an nested loop i can't go outside because some other codes are on my outer loop thats why i need  to trim it inside

Comment: I don't believe it, sorry...

Comment: Thanks, I never thought implode would be useful in that way haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That makes no sense.  If you don't want the last `+` then `rtrim()` after the loop, why inside?

Just create an array and `implode()`:

```
for($i=0; $i<6; $i++){
    $plus[] = 'total'.$i;

}
$plus = implode('+', $plus);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here would be another approach without a need for `trim()` or `implode()`:

```
    $plus = "";
    for($i=0; $i<6; $i++){
        $plus .= 'total'. $i;
        if($i < 5){
            $plus .= "+";
        }
    }
    echo $plus;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps.

```
for($i=0; $i<6; $i++){
    $plus .= 'total'.$i.'+';
    if($i == 5){
        echo rtrim($plus,'+');
    }
}
```